# SED script not matching single in Multiline pattern after line breaks

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to produce a sed script that converts

```
&&a_x* &&b_x;cx &&d_x*
```

into

```
a_x
ax
b_x 
cx 
d_x
dx
```

A `*` should trigger the duplication with removed `_`, a `;` a simple linebreak.

I have a SED script that first inserts the linebreaks (including the operation with the `;`) and then executes a multiple line pattern for the duplication without `_`.

The multiple line pattern works if I move it into a seperate script file and pipe the output of the instructions for executing the linebreaks.

For some strange reason a single script file won't do - which is what I want for maintenance reasons.

Here's the combined version:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
# Remove whitespaces 
s/\ //g 
# Linebreak on &&
s/\&\&/\
\&\&/g
### Linebreak on ; 
s/\;/\
/g
# Remove extra new line
s/\n// 
:extendvars
/^..*\*$/ {
    l                         //DEBUG SWITCH
    h 
    s/\(\&\|\*\)\(\&\|\*\)*//g
    p
    g
    s/\(\&\|_\|-\|\*\)\(\&\|_\|-\|\*\)*//g
    p
    d
    bextendvars;
}
```

The debug switch 'l' in the first line of the multiline pattern should only match lines ending with * but matches all lines and outputs

```
&&a_x*\n&&b_x\bx\n&&c_x*$
```

in the faulty, combined version. When piping it, sed correctly recognizes the pattern:

```
&&a_x*$ ... &&c_x*$
```

Faulty output (combined version):

```
&&a_x*\n&&b_x\nbx\n&&c_x*$ 
a_x 
b_x 
bx 
c_x
ax 
bx 
bx 
cx
```

Correct ouput (piped version):

```
&&a_x*$
a_x 
ax 
&&b_x 
bx 
&&c_x*$
c_x
cx
```

I run the script with

```
sed -f [SCRIPTNAME] <old >new
```

In this version I haved removed the `&&` from `&&b_x` jet.

How can I get SED to recognize the correct pattern even if execute all statements in one script?
Why does SED suddenly fail to match a single line ending with `*`?

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code never loops again doesn't actually have anything to do with the loop condition; it's that inside the loop, you run

```
    d
```

...which aborts the processing of the current input line. That you constructed several lines in the pattern space from the input line is of no consequence; `d` tells sed to stop what it was doing, read the next line of input (if there is one) and start over with that.

Anyway, your approach seems overly complicated to me. I'd suggest (in GNU parlance, because the mechanism is more obvious in GNU sed code)

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

s/\s*(^|&&|;)\s*/\n/g      # split tokens onto several lines, make sure
                           # there's a newline in front of each (so the next
                           # regex matches all)
s/(\n[^\n])_x\*/\1_x\1x/g  # Match lines that end with _x*, expand to
                           # \nfoo_x\nfoox
s/^\n*//                   # remove leading newlines (we put at least one
                           # there in the beginning)
```

You seem to have taken great pains to make the code work with non-GNU sed, so here's a POSIX version that does the same thing:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/[[:space:]]*&&[[:space:]]*/\
/g
s/[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*/\
/g
s/^/\
/
s/\(\n[^\n]\)_x\*/\1_x\1x/g
s/^\
*//
```

This removes whitespaces around the tokens. It seemed like a sensible thing to do. If you don't want that to happen, the space-matching parts will have to be removed from the code, and provisions will have to be made for whitespace at the end of a token line.

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

s/^|&&|;/\n/g
s/(\n[^\n])_x\*([[:blank:]]*)/\1_x\1x\2/g
s/^\n//
```

is a possible adaptation of the GNU sed code.

Answer (score 1):

A simple awk can be more readable than sed here. Try this `awk` command:

```
s='&&a_x* &&b_x;cx &&d_x*'

echo "$s" | awk -F '\\*' -v RS='&&|;' 'NF{s=$1;print s} NF==2{sub(/_/, "", s);print s}'
a_x
ax
b_x
cx
d_x
dx
```

Comment: Oooh, I like that. Shiny. It's noteworthy that not all awks support regex (or even multi-character) `RS`, so given OP's effort to avoid GNUisms in the sed code, I'm not sure that'll work for him, but it's a nice way to do this sort of thing for most people.

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that it is gnu awk

Comment: Yeah shiny indeed, cool alternative solution - I'll put AWK next on my list!